# Jquery Click to Change Form Field Value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
<input type="text" name="frameSelection" id="frameSelection" value="Option 1" />
<a id="change">Change to Option 2</a>
```

When I click on the link I want to change the field value into "Option 2". How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Very simple. Use [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) to attach an event handler to the `click` event, and [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to set the value:

```
$("#change").click(function() {
    $("#frameSelection").val("Option 2");
});
```

As mentioned in other answers, you may want to prevent the default behaviour of the link, but with your code as it currently is in the question (with no `href` attribute on the `a` element) that's not necessary. Just bear it in mind if that could change.

Answer (score 4):

With jQuery:

```
$('#change').click(
    function(e){
        e.preventDefault;  // if your a has an href attribute, this prevents the browser
                           // following that link.
        $('#frameSelection').val("Option 2");
    });
```

References:

- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`e.preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).
- [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).